# Why my character cannot always run his moving animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let me explain.
I coded this for the character you control in my game. Basically, it checks if the current sprite of the gameobject is main_0 (it's not moving) and then if you press the arrows it can move and run the animation. The problem here is that when I execute the game and I try pressing the keys, only in the 50% of the cases the animation of movin works. Does anyone know what's happening?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

 public class MainController : MonoBehaviour
{
string disfname;
void Start()
{

}
void Update()
{
    disfname = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.name;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("moving", false);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("right") && disfname == "main_0")
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("moving", true);
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector3(300000 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(0, Vector3.up);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("left") && disfname == "main_0")
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("moving", true);
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector3(-300000 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, Vector3.up);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("up"))
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 2000 * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("down"))
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, -1000 * Time.deltaTime, 0));
    }
}
```

}

Also thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: altohugh that might not be the issue, you are stopping it at the beginning of the update with gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("moving", false); I would put that in the else section of the "ifs" to stop the animation when the key is not being pressed anymore

Answer (score 0):

You're stopping the animation at the beginning of `Update` and, then, restarting it immediately after. Here's your solution:

```
void Update()
{
   disfname = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.name;

   if (Input.GetKeyDown("right") && disfname == "main_0")
   {
      gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("moving", true);
      gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector3(300000 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
      gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(0, Vector3.up);
   }
   else if (Input.GetKeyDown("left") && disfname == "main_0")
   {
      gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("moving", true);
      gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector3(-300000 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
      gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(180, Vector3.up);
   }
   else
   {
      gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("moving", false);
   }

   // Some other stuff...
}
```

Comment: I made that change, but the animation isn't still fixed, I'll put a video of what happens once I upload it to youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQTbw-D6aOo&feature=youtu.be

As you can see, sometimes the animation executes and sometimes not